# Can an EM wave be represented in terms of dipole?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization, dipole

The direction of propagation is represented by a line. A positive charge moves along this line at velocity c. A negative charge moves along a line that is perpendicular to the direction of propagation and in the plane of polarization. The motion of negative charge along this line is simple harmonic i.e., sinusoidal. Along with this the negative charge has a velocity component identical, in terms of magnitude and direction, to positive charge. The medium is vacuum and the wave is light wave.

I am adding a diagram for better understanding. I compare it to an electromagnetic wave. Can I represent an Electromagnetic wave in this manner?

[image]

This representation is flawed in many ways. But to understand the effect of magnetic field on EM wave this representation will be handy. Is this statement true?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're actually asking.

Comment: I hope this diagram will be useful. If I need to provide more information please feel free to comment.

Comment: _A positive charge moves along this line at velocity $c$_ There are no massless charged particles, so this is impossible. Electromagnetic waves need no medium to propagate.

Comment: I know by representing this way, many laws will be broken. I just wanted to observe if the effect of magnetic field on EM wave will be similar to that on a dipole wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not possible. EM wave is not affected by magnetic fields in vacuum.